# ng-repeat disable my div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I for my stage have to modifie a web site for that i need angularjs i wanted to use the command ng-repeat to display some documentation but when i add ng-repeat in the div it "destroy" it and i cant figure out why...
So there is the code hope u can help me.
There is my js

```
App.controller('doccontroller', [ function(){
return {
        scope: {},
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope){
            $scope.docs = [
                {
                    "id_section" : 0,
                    "description": "RANDOM STUFF",
                    "source": [
                        {
                           "python": "TEXTE",
                            "ruby": "TEXTE",
                            "javascript": "TEXTE"
                        }
                    ]
                },

                {
                    "id_section" : 1, 
                    "description": "RANDOM STUFF",
                    "source": [
                        {
                           "python": "TEXTE",
                            "ruby": "TEXTE",
                            "javascript": "TEXTE"
                        }
                    ]
                },

                {
                    "id_section" : 2, 
                    "description": "RANDOM STUFF",
                    "source": [
                        {
                           "python": "TEXTE",
                            "ruby": "TEXTE",
                            "javascript": "TEXTE"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }       
}
```

])

`There is my route to "include" the controller

```
$routeProvider.when '/docs',
    templateUrl : config.BaseHtml+'/Page/docs.html'
    controller  : 'doccontroller'
```

`
and to finish the html :)

```
<div id="api-docs">
                <div id="methods">
                    <div class="languages">
                        <a class="language selected" data-lang="ruby" href="#">Ruby</a>
                        <a class="language" data-lang="python" href="#">Python</a>
                        <a class="language" data-lang="php" href="#">PHP</a>
                    </div>
                <div>   
                    <div class="method" id="intro">
                        <div class="method-section clearfix">
                            <div class="method-description" ng-repeat="doc in docs">
                                <h3>Introduction</h3>
                                <p>
                                        {{doc.description}}
                                </p> 
                            </div>
                        <div class="method-example">
        <pre>
        <code class="ruby"># All this code is just folololol

        React.api_key = "In here goes your api key!"</code><code class="python"># All this code is just for demonstration purposes

        react.api_key = "In here goes your api key!"</code><code class="php"># All this code is just for demonstration purposes

        React::setApiKey("In here goes your api key!");</code>
        </pre>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

So to say it again, what i need to do is to fill create 1 div / id_section and to fill it with the 
descrition for now.

Comment: what? i dont get it x)

Comment: It should be {{docs.description}} not {{doc.des}}

Comment: your controller definition is not valid..please check docs https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: @TyLo your avatar's name is Ryuzaki..

Answer (score 1):

Change:

`ng-repeat="docs in docs"`

to:

`ng-repeat="doc in docs"`

Also, in your code you have a call to `{{ doc.des }}`, which probably should be `{{ doc.description }}`

Comment: Well, im sorry i did some testes before posting and changed  some name in french to english for the  post, forgot to change that. Even tho i did what u said still not working

Comment: tryed some stuff if u prefer. Im pretty sad no one can help me its maybe bc i dont explain my self correctly

Comment: @TyLo It's also difficult to see what the problem is here. Have you  tried isolating your code into something like JSFiddle? Have you checked the link Asik posted as a comment?